# How to build a mixin factory in TypeScript with a precisely typed return value

Tags: typescript, mixins

I need to build a mixin factory in TypeScript that can extend any class just by adding a property enabling the unique identification of its instances. This is the general form it needs to have (no types added yet):

```
function Unique(BaseClass) {
  return class extends BaseClass {
    public readonly uniqueId = Symbol();
  };
}
```

If I type this function as in TypeScript's handbook, the inferred type for the return value of this function does not contain enough information. For example, if do something like this:

```
const myUniqueDog = new (Unique(Dog))();
```

Typescript knows that `myUniqueDog` has the `uniqueId` property, but knows nothing of the properties and methods inherited from `Dog`.

Is it possible for the return value of this function to keep the type information both of the class being extended and the `Unique` interface? I have tried different options along these lines but it doesn't work:

```
// Two constructor definitions needed because some classes to be extended are abstract
type ConcreteConstructor<T = {}> = new(...args: any[]) => T;
type AbstractConstructor<T = {}> = abstract new(...args: any[]) => T;
type Constructor<T = {}> = ConcreteConstructor<T> | AbstractConstructor<T>;

type IUnique<T extends {}> = T & { readonly uniqueId: symbol };

function Unique<T extends {}>(BaseClass: Constructor<T>): ConcreteConstructor<IUnique<T>> {
  return class extends BaseClass implements IUnique<T> {
    public readonly uniqueId = Symbol();
  };
}
```

The error is the following:

> Type 'typeof (Anonymous class)' is not assignable to type 'ConcreteConstructor<IUnique>'.
> Type '(Anonymous class)' is not assignable to type 'IUnique'.
> Type '(Anonymous class)' is not assignable to type 'T'.
> '(Anonymous class)' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'object'.ts(2322)

Is there a some way to achieve this? I need it so that other factories employing this Unique function have correct return types without type assertions.

Comment: `// Two constructor definitions needed because some classes to be extended are abstract` No, [`abstract` construct signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-2.html#abstract-construct-signatures) are subtypes of abstract constructors so you only need `abstract` if you want to accept both types.

Comment: Also, according to the docs for abstract construct signatures, if you accept `abstract` base classes, then you must return an `abstract` extended class, because you don't know that the passed in class doesn't have `abstract` properties that the mixin doesn't implement.  If you want to break this rule you will need a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) or the equivalent inside the implementation of `Unique()` (but you run the risk of doing something bad).  Is that okay with you?

Comment: What do you think of [this](https://tsplay.dev/m3zXEN) solution?  If that works for you I'll write up an answer.  If it doesn't, please edit the question to include a [mcve] of the use cases you need to support.  Let me know!

Comment: @jcalz Thank you very much! My current abstract classes don't have abstract properties, so I had overlooked the problem they would entail. At first I supposed that returning an abstract class would require further extension of all the mixins in order to instantiate them. I considered reconverting my classes to concrete classes (it wouldn't be such a big deal), but surprisingly TypeScript allows direct instantiation of the mixin if the base class is concrete. Therefore your solution is perfect, doesn't require type assertions, and allows me to use `IUnique` as a type alias for mixin instances.

Comment: I never get why this technique (regardless of being used by either TS or JS) is referred to as *mixin* while the underlying code is not doing anything related to mixin and/or trait based composition but is entirely class/inheritance based (a factory returning a class which extends the very class passed to it; and then instantiating objects from this returned class, with each object even reflecting the pure inheritance by its prototype chain). Using a factory which encapsulates but still executes class extension does not all of a sudden shift the underlying concept from *inheritance* to *mixin*